# How can I accept all changes when opening a Word document with Openoffice?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice

I sometimes get Word documents from my co-workers to put their content on the web. Sometimes, the changes that the previous editor of the document made are visible.

Additions are underlined and deletions are stricken through. Now I have to click on every addition/deletion to accept it.

Is it possible to somehow accept all changes and be done with it? Or even better, ignore the history all together? I couldn't care less what the last edits where, I'm just the guy who cleans up the formatting and puts it on the web :)

Comment: Why don't you just use word?

Comment: I'm a Linux user. Using word processors isn't part of my daily routine (I'm a programmer), but my co-workers only give me the evil eye when I ask them for valid HTML instead of Word documents :)

Comment: I have colleagues who insist that *everything*, even the tiniest fragment of text, must be in Word or Powerpoint format. I was once sent the source code of a webpage as a Word document.

Comment: @pavium  Tell them: copying & pasting code to/from MSWord is dangerous.  You can inadvertently copy MSWord special characters, i.e. the MSWord single quote ‘  ’ which is different than '  '.  If you get MSWord single quotes in your code, and the compiler doesn't catch it, you'll have a terrible time figuring out why your application keeps crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off change tracking for the document:  http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Tracking_changes

Comment: You are welcome.  Same principle would apply if you were using MSWord.

Answer (score 5):

Just for posterity and for everybody that googles `openoffice accept all changes`:

**Edit** → **Changes** → **Accept or Reject** → **Accept All**